# Using WCF http web service in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services, asmx

We have web application written in **ASP.NET** webforms with some asmx web services. Now we want to add some toher web services, which will serve different purpose than the old ones. We decided to use **WCF** framework.

My colleague created a new project in our solution, where he implemented the web service. Unfortunatelly he did not use the WCF* project templates, but normal console application with the following method for starting the WS:

```
public static void StartWS() {
  if (_selfHost!=null)
    StopWS();

  Uri baseAdress = new Uri(WSIntegrationService.ServerUrl);
  _selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WSIntegrationService), baseAdress);
  _selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWSIntegrationService), new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None), WSIntegrationService.EndPointName);
  _selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
  _selfHost.Open();
  logger.Info("Integration WS started on adress " + baseAdress);
}
```

Now I have to integrate the project to our web application (another project in solution).

1. What is the easiest way to do it?
2. How can I ensure that both - the old asmx service as well as the new WCF service is operational?

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was not that hard:

1. In web app project choose Add New Item -> WCF Service. This should create Service.svc, Service.svc.cs and IService.cs. It also modifies your web config. Now you can try if it works, with the auto generated method `DoWork`. Simply use something like SoapUI app to do that. ALso you can try to browse to the svc file and check the wsdl (e.g.`http://localhost:2753/WSIntegration/Service1.svc?wsdl`)
2. Delete the files IService.cs and Service.csv.cs. Modify the Service.svc file, so it contains just the reference to the class implementing the WS, e.g. like this:

That's all. I haven't deploy the solution to the IIS yet, but I don't expect any problems there. As soon as I will do that. I will update the unswer if any additional steps will be needed.